# How does the browser determines if proxy is 'not available' when using PAC file

Tags: javascript, browser, proxy, pac

I have the following PAC file code:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    return "PROXY proxy1:8080" + "PROXY proxy2:8080; ";
};
```

According to Java this should work as follows (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/821-0053/adyrr/index.html):

> In the following example, the return value tells the browser to use
>   the proxy called w3proxy.example.com on port 8080. If that proxy is
>   unavailable, the browser uses the proxy called proxy1.example.com on
>   port 8080:
>
> PROXY w3proxy.example.com:8080; PROXY proxy1.example.com:8080

When testing in lab it seems that explorer is using those proxies in load balancing mode. I have not seen any probing of those proxies in wireshark but yet failover occurs after some re-loads of a website.

How does the browser determines weather the proxy is alive or not? 
According to some websites it says that the browser also uses those proxies in load balancing, Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A healthy user-agent will simply pick up the first proxy returned by the PAC file and try to forward traffic to the IP address returned for its domain name.

Now, either that IP may not respond to the SYN packets from the client's system on that port or it may serve its own page if it's not running a web proxy service. In the first case, the browser will switch to the secondary proxy after a couple of TCP time-outs that last hardly a couple of seconds(but it may vary depending on configuration of TCP/IP stack on the client). In the second case, the user-agent/browser is happy because it gets a response to the request even if it is not the web resource it wanted to access.

- For the first example, you could try using 4.2.2.2:80 as first proxy and observe. It is an NTP server and does not listen on 80, so you'll time out soon.
- For the second example, you could try using purple.com:80 as first proxy. It is a regular web server. No matter what requests you send, it will serve its own page but the PAC file renderer would not try the secondary proxy because it is getting a response.

Now comes the scenario where the proxy name resolves to a IP:port socket that is open and is running a web proxy service. Let's consider a case where the web server only likes requests from certain white-listed source IPs and this web proxy isn't listed in there.

- The proxy server will respond to the client and try to establish a connection with the intended web server and the server will not respond. The number of attempts that the proxy server makes to access the web resource in question and the time for which it keeps its connection with the client open depends on the implementation of the proxy service.
- After a specific duration, the connection will time out and the client's user-agent will try the next proxy statement available in the PAC file.

This was the response to how the user-agent, usually a web browser, determines whether the proxy is alive or not.

Now, coming to your second question about load-balancing, that is definitely not correct. By default, the browser will switch to the next proxy statement only in the scenarios I mentioned above. But if you want, you can call the function myIpAddress() in your PAC file and parse the subnet part of the IP address returned by it. Then, you could apply separate proxy statements for different subnets. I've seen quite a few organisations use this poor technique to achieve source IP-based load-balancing through PAC file configuration.

HTH!

Comment: Please check this https://gist.github.com/larytet/c3a97d242c2d0821c5600a0f0a3808e7  Two SYN packets are sent to two different Proxy servers simultaneously, followed by two HTTP GET. This is Chrome.

Comment: But what does your pac file look like?

Comment: The PAC returns two IP addresses. My (our) theory is that  the Chrome caches the proxy IP per URL

Comment: IE 10 caches the Proxy IP addresses as well. I am not surprised that browsers try to avoid executing a non-trivial JS before a TCP SYN.